# twilio in incoming call when agent disconnect the call user is not disconnecting

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

this is my twiml what I m using to connect the call-

```
<Response>
 <Dial action="dailemptyqueueurl"> 
<Client statusCallbackEvent="initiated ringing answered completed" statusCallback="twilio_call_notification_handler.php" statusCallbackMethod="POST">cleint</Client> 
</Dial>
 <Redirect>holdmusic</Redirect> 
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a slight hangover from my previous advice, so sorry for that.

Firstly, when [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) has an [action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action), it will go onto that URL instead of continuing with the TwiML and going to the [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) in this case. So watch out for that.

Secondly, because we have used this technique then calls don't just end. However, you are using, I believe, Twilio Client with your agent. So, when you hangup the call on the agent end, you could make a request to your server to use the [REST API to hang up](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) the user end too.